# LSTM input and output dimensions in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused about LSTM input/output dimensions, specifically in keras library. How do keras return 2D output while its input is 3D? I know it can return 3D output using “return_sequence = Trure,” but if return_sequence = False, how can it deal with 3D and produces 2D output?
For example, if input data of shape (32, 16, 20),  32 batch size, 16 timestep, 20 features, and output of shape  (32, 100), 32 batch size, 100 hidden states; how keras processes input of 3d and returns output 2d.
Additionally, how can concatenate input and hidden state if they don’t have the exact dimensions?

Comment: This is described in the documentation, and it is pretty simple, 2D output is returned by returning only the last timestep.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in the link below:
https://mmuratarat.github.io/2019-01-19/dimensions-of-lstm
it's very helpful!